# Displaying SVG file on android real device

Tags: android, button, svg, imageview

I want to display svg file in android. I use `Library svg-android` . However it does not work. i downloaded the sample project . It gives 'app1 is stopped` error on device. Also, i tried the hardware part. I used this code part.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(),R.raw.listitemsvg);
 //   Picture picture = svg.getPicture();
    Drawable drawable = svg.createPictureDrawable();
   // Button button1 =   (Button) findViewById( R.id.button1 ) ;
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1 );
    image.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
     image.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    // button1.setBackground(drawable);
```

As you see, first i tried it on button view. After that, i tried it on imageview. Both do not work.I want to know why it does not works on android device?

Logcat:

> 08-21 23:10:31.800: I/dalvikvm(4660): Could not find method com.larvalabs.svgandroid.SVGParser.getSVGFromResource, referenced from method com.example.budogui.MainActivity.onCreate
>   08-21 23:10:31.800: W/dalvikvm(4660): VFY: unable to resolve static method 8440: Lcom/larvalabs/svgandroid/SVGParser;.getSVGFromResource (Landroid/content/res/Resources;I)Lcom/larvalabs/svgandroid/SVG;
>   08-21 23:10:31.800: D/dalvikvm(4660): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000f
>   08-21 23:10:31.880: D/AndroidRuntime(4660): Shutting down VM
>   08-21 23:10:31.880: W/dalvikvm(4660): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ec3930)
>   08-21 23:10:31.880: E/AndroidRuntime(4660): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   08-21 23:10:31.880: E/AndroidRuntime(4660): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.larvalabs.svgandroid.SVGParser

File:
http://imgh.us/listitemsvg.svg

Comment: "It gives 'app1 is stopped` error on device" -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: this is really useful info for us. Thnks. I still have problem. I could not share photo due to less reputation

Comment: I am not sure what photo you are referring to. If you cannot interpret the Java stack trace, paste the stack trace itself into your question as text. Beyond that, if you have some images you wish to have as part of your question, upload the images somewhere and link to them from your question.

Comment: you are right. i edited

Comment: Sounds like perhaps you did not add the library properly to the project. If you are using Eclipse, you should have copied the JAR file to your `libs/` directory and done nothing else.

Comment: it is really interesting. i added library using eclipse GUI. Eclipse also sees all methods . I mean it does not give any errors like 'could not find' when build time. i will try your opinion as soon as possible

Comment: "i added library using eclipse GUI. Eclipse also sees all methods" -- that is because you are satisfying *compile time* requirements. However, the JAR is not being packaged in the APK, so the code is not available at runtime. Undo your changes to the build path, then move the JAR into `libs/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more easy if you transform all images to Base64, and so lately make bitmaps whith that for example.

```
public Bitmap getBitmap(String image) {
    byte[] image_bytes = Base64.decode(image.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image_bytes, 0, image_bytes.length);
    return bitmap;
}
```

or

```
public Bitmap resizeBitmap(Bitmap original_image, float width, float height){
    float originalWidth = original_image.getWidth(), originalHeight = original_image.getHeight();
    float scale = width/originalWidth;
    float xTranslation = 0.0f, yTranslation = (height - originalHeight * scale)/2.0f;

    Bitmap background = Bitmap.createBitmap((int)width, (int)height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(background);
    Matrix transformation = new Matrix();
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    transformation.postTranslate(xTranslation, yTranslation);
    transformation.preScale(scale, scale);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);

    canvas.drawBitmap(original_image, transformation, paint);
    return background;
}
```

Comment: does this work like SVG file ? i have resolution problem so i wanted to work with svg. if this works, i probably prefer this

Comment: Indeed, this form is the best for images with support for multiple resolutions, I always do